# linux terminal command with a pipe in c code

Tags: c, linux, command, pipe

I'm trying to execute the Linux command "ls -l | tail -n 2" with a simple pipe in a c code.

I added your tips and now this works but the output isn't exactly as it should be. It prints the output in a single line instead of two and waits for a user input to close.
here is the new code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "sys/wait.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main()
{
    char line[100];
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    int status;
    char* ls_arguments[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
    char* tail_arguments[] = {"tail", "-n", "2", NULL};
    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)//ls client
    {
        close(1);
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        execvp("ls", ls_arguments);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)//tail client
    {
        close(0);
    close(fd[1]);
        dup(fd[0]);
        execvp("tail", tail_arguments);
    }
    wait(pid, 0, WNOHANG);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
}
```

this should run the "ls -l" command and output to the pipe and the next "tail" client would get it as input and run the "tail -n 2" command and print out the final output but the terminal prints nothing. Any help?

Comment: There's no point in putting code after `execvp()`, since it never returns unless it gets an error.

Comment: You need to `close(fd[0])` in the `ls` client and `close(fd[1])` in the `tail` client before they each call `exec`.

Comment: And the parent process needs to close both of them.

Comment: but if i close the pipe in the ls client it will be closed in the tail client right?

Comment: No. Closing an fd in one process has no effect on other processes. The pipe doesn't go away until all processes close it.

Comment: what do you mean by closing the forks? how do i know i didnt close them before they finished running?

Comment: I never said "closing the forks".

Comment: so what do you mean by "the parent process needs to close both of them"?

Comment: It needs to close both `fd[0]` and `fd[1]`.

Comment: The point is that `tail` reads from its `stdin` pipe until it gets EOF. But the pipe doesn't return EOF until the write end of the pipe is closed. And that doesn't happen until all processes close it.

Comment: please look in the edited code above

Comment: I don't think it's actually your problem, but I strongly recommend using `dup2()` instead of `dup()`.  That ensures that you dupe onto the correct FD number, and also relieves you from any need to separately close that FD before the call.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is not such `wait` function, here is what the `man` says:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t wait(int *status);

pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

I think you meant to use `waitpid`.

Then, you child process doesn't finish because the pipe is still opened somewhere: in the parent. Indeed you should first close the descriptors and then wait for your childs process. I would write:

```
  close(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);
  wait(NULL); // Wait for the first child to finish
  wait(NULL); // Wait fot the second one
  return 0;
}
```

Instead of:

```
  wait(pid, 0, WNOHANG);
  close(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);
}
```